# Hololens video stream with spatial data

Tags: c#, image-processing, camera, hololens

I'm using the hololens and I'm trying to save a video stream with the world/projection matrices avaiable.
I've been trying to just take a sequence of pictures and save the data, but I can't find a way to save the image and the matrices.

When saving to disk, there is no option to get the photocaptureframe (which contains the matrix data), when saving to memory, I seem to not be able to save the image to disk. 
I tried using the following methode, but this seemed to crash my unity program:

```
List<byte> imageBufferList = new List<byte>();
photoCaptureFrame.CopyRawImageDataIntoBuffer(imageBufferList);
byte[] myArrayImage = imageBufferList.ToArray();
```

And then use this to convert the byte array:

```
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
return Image.FromStream(mStream);
```

After which I save the result.

When I remove the memorystream thing, the program doesn't crash (but it doesn't save my image either).

I've been looking all over the internet but there are a lot of vague statements about it 
a) not beeing possible
b) using the memorystream (but that crashes)

Any suggestions?
If anyone knows a way to save all the the matrix (projection and world) data per frame and the corresponding frame for a video stream, it would be a great help.

Edit: I also tried to look into https://github.com/VulcanTechnologies/HoloLensCameraStream but this seems to give problems with newer Unity versions. Any remarks about this?

To clarify my end goal:
When filming, the program should save all frames and the corresponding matrices, for example:

Frame_01, Frame_02, Frame_03, ... (.jpg/png/...)

World_matrix_01, World_matrix_02, ... (.txt)

Projection_matrix_01, Projection_matrix_02,...  (.txt)

Comment: Well, as I didn't find a way to fix this problem on more recent versions of Unity/visual studio, I'll just leave this here for other people.

I used Unity5.6.3 to get the  https://github.com/VulcanTechnologies/HoloLensCameraStream working. This enabled me to get the needed information.

If someone finds a way to use more recent versions of unity, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: I also tried to look into https://github.com/VulcanTechnologies/HoloLensCameraStream but this seems to give problems with newer Unity versions. Any remarks about this?

I used it and it worked very well in Unity 2018.3.13f1. You can only test in Hololens out of debug mode.